# What should be done with answers that consist almost entirely of material copied from external sites?

Tags: discussion, moderation

[This answer](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/71552/39614) started life with only material copied from a Reddit thread, though the user did provide a link to the original material. Then a second section was added in the form of a long (by the standards of Stack Exchange answers) essay that feels meandering in the context of the question. This material is also copied in its entirety from an external site, also with a link to the original.

This answer seems to provide a shallow survey of the history of music and a rant about why the public no longer cares about classical music, with none of the material generated by the user who posted the answer. Further, it isn't clear to me that this post is an actual answer to the OP's question, which was: *Why aren't there composers writing in a classical style today?* Obviously the OP question rested on a false premise: there are *many* composers working in classical styles today, a fact pointed to by many of the other answers to this question.

This answer does not seem to me like a suitable answer for this site, but I am not sure how it should be flagged. I don't think that it actually answers the question, but I do think that it is an attempt at an answer, so probably it should not be flagged as NAA. It isn't plagiarism, since the material is attributed. But there is no original content from the answerer here, and it is difficult to see what the answerer is trying to say with all of this (other people's) verbiage.

Maybe this calls for a custom moderator flag?

---

EDIT: Bumping this question in the interest of further discussion on the general issue. (The specific post that prompted the question has been attended to.)

Answer (score 6):

To speak more generally, my understanding is that an answer that primarily consists of properly **attributed** and edited quotes that **effectively answer the question** should be fine.

That said, the content necessary to give the correct credit and also link the quoted passages together and explain how they answer the question is usually not trivial.

Answer (score 5):

I have left a comment - I'm not sure it would need a specific custom flag, but thank you for bringing it to our attention.

After full review of the post and the plagiarized content, I have deleted the entire post pending improvements from the user concerned.

Down voting and flagging for a mod are both appropriate in this type of scenario.

Comment: What in my answer was 'plagiarized'? Note that the OP overhead stated 'It isn't plagiarism, since the material is attributed.' What if I reproduced content from a book?

Comment: If you copied the entire book, then yeah - we'd take a dim view of that. The idea is to provide your answer, supported by quotes as needed, not just copy the whole lot over. That is plagiarism, no matter what the OP wrote up there. And it does turn into a rant/complaint, rather than an actual answer. If a post has numerous highly voted answers, including an accepted one, you need to think about what a new answer will add.

Comment: @Greek-Area51Proposal your post falls under the definition of direct plagiarism which is defined as ["the word-for-word transcription of a section of someone else's work, without attribution __and without quotation marks__"](https://www.bowdoin.edu/studentaffairs/academic-honesty/common-types.shtml) (emphasis added).  You can't just cite a source and not distinguish between  what is your work and what is not. The whole point of citation is to know whether the content is the author's or someone else's work. Skeptics SE's content has plenty of citations with attribution for comparison.

Comment: @Dom Please see my edit to that answer.

Comment: @greek - your edit does not help at all. You have still just copy and pasted the content from the other sites.

Comment: And your other answer is also unacceptable here as it falls under our link only prohibition